# Can ListIterator safely be susbtituted for Iterator? (Implementing a CopyOnWrite wrapper for List)

Tags: java, list, collections, copy-on-write

I have many instance in code where a Collection, most usually a List is returned from a method and to account for the caller possibly altering that list, a defensive copy is made.

The JDK does not seem to provide a wrapper for this purpose, so I'm trying to roll my own (Note: java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList is *not* what I'm looking for here).

Schematically, what I'm trying is:

```
public class CopyOnWriteList<E> extends List<E> {

    protected List<E> list;
    protected boolean isCopied;

    public CopyOnWriteList(List<E> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    private void ensureCopy() {
        if (!isCopied) {
            list = new ArrayList<E>(list);
            isCopied = true;
        }
    }

    public E get(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        ensureCopy();
        return list.add(e);
    }

    // ... many more simple methods

}
```

For most of the API this is simple enough, but looking at java.util.ArrayList I found, that for the method iterator() it returns a different implementation than for listIterator(), although is ListIterator extends its Iterator and it *doesn't* add any new members.

I wonder if there is a deeper reason behind this - I planned simply to implement iterator() and listIterator() all returning the same type of iterator - a ListIterator. Is there any logical reason why one should *not* return a ListIterator from the iterator()-method?

Answer (score 1):

ListIterator extends Iterator. So if you return an object that implements ListIterator then it obviously also implements Iterator. But you also can decide to return different object that only implements Iterator, because the implementation could be more effective. The decision is up to you.

Comment: Well, thats obvious. The question is *specifically* why one would *not* return a ListIterator from iterator(), as is done in java.util.ArrayList. And its *not* an optimized implementation either - I checked the implementation. So *why* did they implement it that way - is there a sensible reason for *that*.

Comment: Which implementation? In [OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.iterator%28%29) it's different implementation for Iterator and ListIterator. As for the question why did they implement it that way, they did it because they could and they could have plenty of reasons to do it that way. And it is nice OOP approach - as a user of the API you will receive the object that is meeting the contract specified by the interface and you should not be bothered by the real implementation of it :)